# How view image from database by using php

Tags: php

I am using localhost. I insert image in database blob. I am trying for show image. But I am fail. Image does not show. Database have three field **id,name,image**. Trying this code.

**uimage.php**

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("task_database");

$image=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM image WHERE id=1");
$image=mysql_fetch_assoc($image);
$image=$image['image'];
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo $image;
?>
```

and using this code in **index.php** page:

```
echo "Image Uploaded.<p />Your image:<p /><img src=uimage.php>";
```

But image did not show. Please help me. 
My Full Code here: http://codepad.org/hJ8qucml

Comment: I removed header line now it did not work.. @Arif_suhail_123

Comment: Src=uimage.php??? Why you writing this?

Comment: bcz i using hard code id=1 @Ashes

Comment: src="uimage.php" now error @Arif_suhail_123

Comment: my index.php code here: http://codepad.org/hJ8qucml  @Arif_suhail_123

Comment: sorry bro i can not understand @Arif_suhail_123. you can your success image insert and showing code

Comment: yah i read but what's problem bro..@Arif_suhail_123

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest type of handling images in PHP-based websites is to save the images with the its id as name in a separated folder and just saving the id in database! 
i really recommend you this type of working with images!

Answer (score 0):

These are quick examples and you should validate any data being passed that is being used in a query. Check out Mysqli.

Using inline base64 encoding:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("task_database");

$result=mysql_query("SELECT name, myimg FROM image WHERE id=1");
$image=mysql_fetch_row($result);
$imagesrc=$image[1];
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($imagesrc).'"/>';
```

Using PHP file to call the image:

```
<img src="image.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" />
```

image.php

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("task_database");

$result=mysql_query("SELECT name, myimg FROM image WHERE id=1");
$image=mysql_fetch_row($result);
$imagesrc=$image[1];

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
echo $imagesrc;
```

?>

Comment: How did you save the image to the db? Can you give us the output of $image.